# Limits of writing to Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, persistent-storage

We've been directed to rebuild what is essentially a form that can have many potential sub inputs (ranging from 1 to 100 inputs).

The change that has me concerned is that, we want to write each field for each input as it's typed, transported over Websockets.

For example if a user typed "hello", we would write to Postgres 5 times: for "h", "he", "hel", "hell", "hello".

I get that this is nice on the user end because it's saved as they go and they don't have to worry about "saving" the form. However, I'm concerned that we will push up against issues with writing to Postgres so much.

We're using a Postgres instance with 4 GB RAM, 64 GB storage, 120 connections.

At what level of writes/second should we be concerned and what ways can we measure and mitigate against issues?

Comment: You should only send the input to the database once the users submits the form, not on each and every keystroke

Answer (score 0):

You should be concerned if you start having more than a couple of thousand writes per second. You won't be able to support even substantially lower update rates unless you can make use of HOT updates (no indexes on the modified columns) because autovacuum wouldn't be able to keep up.

I think that the concept of storing partial user input in the database is madness. Your application should wait until input is finished, then verify that the data are correct and only then store it in the database.